# Python access violation

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, matplotlib, ptvs

Here is a `Python 3.4` user, in `VS 2013` and `PTVS`...

I'd written a program to plot something by `Matplotlib`... The output had been generating and everything was ok...

So, I closed `VS` and now I've opened it again after an hour, running the very script, but this time as soon as I press `F5`, a window appears and says `Python has stopped working`...

There is a short log in the `output` window, which asserts that:

`The program '[9952] python.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Who could decrypt this error, please?!...

Kind Regards

.........................................

Edit:

I just tested again with no change... The error has been changed to:

`The program '[11284] python.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Debug shows that when the program points to the drawing command of the `matloptlib`, i.e. `plt.show()`, this crash will happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the attempts sounds futile...

Even removing the `VS` is a challenging stuff... and as people consider, changing the OS is the most stable way to get rid of `VS` in the presence of such anomalies regarding its libraries...

So... I changed the OS... and installed the `VS` and `PTVS` again...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your python and PTVS. Try to remove every .pyc file and have another go at it